# Turning string date "Thursday 19th April 2012" into datetime for manipulation

Tags: php, mysql, variables, date, field

I have a field in my table that holds strings in the form

```
"Thursday 19th April 2012"
```

How would i go about altering this in either MYSQL or PHP so that i could perform a manipulation and find the difference between 2 dates?
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do at PHP side (for version 5.3 or above):-

a) `$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("l dS F Y",$dateFromDB);`

( http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

b) `$interval = $newDate->diff($datetime2);`

(http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

You can see the date string format at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

In php, you could use **strtotime** function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

And then absolute value of subtraction of the two values would give you the difference in seconds.